# New MT4 broker. Lot size calculation 10 times larger than previous broker for certain instruments

Tags: mql4

This code has worked for me automating the calculating of lot size until I started using a new broker. Trading using this code on the new broker opens a position 10 times larger. If I wanted to risk $500, it will risk $5000 instead. I'm sure it's something simple but I can't figure it out right now. Does anyone have any ideas on what could be the issue?

Point value and Tick value is the same.

This code calculates the correct lot size for every instrument except NSDQ and SPY, where it's 10 times the size. What could the problem be?

```
         riskticks=MathAbs(myEntry-mySL)/SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_SIZE);
         tickvalue=SymbolInfoDouble(Symbol(),SYMBOL_TRADE_TICK_VALUE);
         riskcash=currBet;
         lotsize=riskcash/(riskticks*tickvalue);
         lotsize_1=NormalizeDouble(lotsize*(input_takePartialsPercent*.01),2);
         
         mySL = NormalizeDouble(mySL,digits);
         myEntry = NormalizeDouble(myEntry,digits);
         myTP = NormalizeDouble(myTP,digits);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `/10` at `lotsize=riskcash/(riskticks*tickvalue)`?

Comment: Then it would be 1/10th the size for my old broker. It also works fine for every instrument except indices, SPY, NSDQ

Comment: Then maybe better to poll the current broker for minimal lotsize: https://docs.mql4.com/marketinformation/marketinfo